# How To Get Total Download and Total Upload That Can Reach More Than 4GB Calculation Coding Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a project delphi 7 named Simple Tunnel
and one of the features is to calculating total download or total upload from network internet

like this pict:
[Simple Tunnel - Rev8.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ejEb.png)
i use the function:

```
function BytesToFriendlyString(Value : DWord) : string;
const
  OneKB = 1024;
  OneMB = OneKB * 1024;
  OneGB = OneMB * 1024;
begin
  if Value < OneKB then
    Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 B',Value)
  else
    if Value < OneMB then
      Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 KB', Value / OneKB)
    else
      if Value < OneGB then
        Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 MB', Value / OneMB)
    else
      if Value > OneGB then
        Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 GB', Value / OneGB)
end; (*BytesToFriendlyString*)
```

adn on timer  i place this function

```
..........................
if (MagRasCon.ConnectState = RASCS_Connected) then
    begin
        MagRasPer.GetPerfStats ;

        edtTotalUP.Text := BytesToFriendlyString (MagRasPer.PerfXmitCur [0]);
        edtTotalDL.Text := BytesToFriendlyString (MagRasPer.PerfRecvCur [0]);
```

it work to count the total download or total upload on this network internet ,, but always stop count at total 4GB 
even though it count 4.74GB on Proxifier..

How to make it can count more than 4GB..??

Answer (score 1):

`DWORD` is an unsigned 32 bit integer. The maximum value is 2^32, or 4GB. That's the problem. You need a variable type that can hold larger values. Use `Int64` a signed 64 bit type. Modern Delphi have `UInt64`, unsigned 64 bit, but not Delphi 7. Still a signed `Int64` will meet your needs.

Comment: okay thanks... i'll try change DWORD to Int64 now.. i hope it can count more than 4gb..

Comment: You don't need to hope. It goes to 2^63.

Comment: Shouldn't MagRas support int64 also for this to work?

Answer (score -1):

Your function accepts a DWORD paramter, which is a type defined in Windows.pas as

```
type
  DWORD = Cardinal;
```

The `Cardinal` type is an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a range of 0 to 4294967295. Since that high value is 4GB, there is no way to make it count higher than 4GB.

If Delphi 7 supports Int64, and MagRasPer supports INt64, you can use that to get above 4GB. If either (or both) of them does not, you cannont.

Comment: Delphi 7 has signed Int64

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks. I thought I remembered it did, but wasn't sure. I don't have a copy installed anywhere to check. I don't know what MagRasPer is, so I don't know if it supports Int64 either. (I'm assuming that MagRasPer is part of Angus Johnson's TMagRas stuff, but don't know for sure.)